# Pinescript: How can I skip the first entry in a strategy?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I try to count the entry conditions and if the counter is on 2 to take the entry. But it doesnt work.

Do I have to make a loop?

```
int delay = 0
if crossLong
    delay +1

if crossLong and delay > 1
    strategy.entry()
```

Thanks

Comment: This code will not even compile. Please show us at least some effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pine script variables resets on each bar. That means that in your case `delay` variable will never be equal to more than 1.
If you don't want it to reset, you'll need to use the `var` keyword, and manage the `delay` variable yourself. For example:

```
var int delay = 0

if crossLong
    delay += 1

if crossLong and delay > 1
    strategy.entry()
    delay := 0
```